# Angular fail to serve

Tags: angular

I am developing Web using Angular and NX workspace.
It is the following environment and App was created on nx workspace.
However, if you keep the App, the following error occurs continuously.
I have searched here and reinstalled @ angular-devkit / build-kit, but the result is the same.
How do I solve this?

*Error

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
    Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(outputPath)
```

*Envronment

Node Version = v10.15.3

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.7
Node: 10.15.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 8.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.7
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.7
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.6
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.7
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.6
@angular/cli                      9.1.7
@angular/http                     7.2.16
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.7
@schematics/angular               9.1.6
@schematics/update                0.901.7
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.9.3
webpack                           4.42.0
```

My angular.json is here.

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "projects": {
    "testbed": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@nrwl/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "apps/testbed",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/testbed/src",
      "prefix": "stela-fes",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/apps/testbed",
            "index": "apps/testbed/src/index.html",
            "main": "apps/testbed/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "apps/testbed/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "apps/testbed/tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "apps/testbed/src/favicon.ico",
              "apps/testbed/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": ["apps/testbed/src/styles.scss"],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "apps/testbed/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "apps/testbed/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "testbed:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "testbed:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "testbed:build"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "apps/testbed/tsconfig.app.json",
              "apps/testbed/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**", "!apps/testbed/**"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "apps/testbed/jest.config.js",
            "tsConfig": "apps/testbed/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "passWithNoTests": true,
            "setupFile": "apps/testbed/src/test-setup.ts"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "testbed-e2e": {
      "root": "apps/testbed-e2e",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/testbed-e2e/src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/cypress:cypress",
          "options": {
            "cypressConfig": "apps/testbed-e2e/cypress.json",
            "tsConfig": "apps/testbed-e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "devServerTarget": "testbed:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "testbed:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": ["apps/testbed-e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**", "!apps/testbed-e2e/**"]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "login-proc": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "libs/login-proc",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/login-proc/src",
      "prefix": "stela-fes",
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "libs/login-proc/tsconfig.lib.json",
              "libs/login-proc/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "./libs/assets/",
                "output": "./assets"
              }
            ],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**", "!libs/login-proc/**"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/login-proc/jest.config.js",
            "tsConfig": "libs/login-proc/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "passWithNoTests": true,
            "setupFile": "libs/login-proc/src/test-setup.ts"
          }
        }
      },
      "schematics": {
        "@nrwl/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      }
    },
    "stim_testspec_mgr": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@nrwl/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "apps/stim_testspec_mgr",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/stim_testspec_mgr/src",
      "prefix": "stela-fes",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/apps/stim_testspec_mgr",
            "index": "apps/stim_testspec_mgr/src/index.html",
            "main": "apps/stim_testspec_mgr/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "apps/stim_testspec_mgr/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "apps/stim_testspec_mgr/tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "apps/stim_testspec_mgr/src/favicon.ico",
              "apps/stim_testspec_mgr/src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "./libs/assets/",
                "output": "./assets"
              }
            ],
            "styles": ["apps/stim_testspec_mgr/src/styles.scss"],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "apps/stim_testspec_mgr/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "apps/stim_testspec_mgr/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "stim_testspec_mgr:build",
            "outputPath": "dist/stim_testspec_mgr",
            "main": "src/main.server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "stim_testspec_mgr:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "stim_testspec_mgr:build"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "apps/stim_testspec_mgr/tsconfig.app.json",
              "apps/stim_testspec_mgr/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**", "!apps/stim_testspec_mgr/**"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "apps/stim_testspec_mgr/jest.config.js",
            "tsConfig": "apps/stim_testspec_mgr/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "passWithNoTests": true,
            "setupFile": "apps/stim_testspec_mgr/src/test-setup.ts"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "stela-svc": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "libs/stela-svc",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/stela-svc/src",
      "prefix": "stela-fes",
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "libs/stela-svc/tsconfig.lib.json",
              "libs/stela-svc/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**", "!libs/stela-svc/**"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/stela-svc/jest.config.js",
            "tsConfig": "libs/stela-svc/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "passWithNoTests": true,
            "setupFile": "libs/stela-svc/src/test-setup.ts"
          }
        }
      },
      "schematics": {
        "@nrwl/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      }
    },
    "stela-app": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "libs/stela-app",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/stela-app/src",
      "prefix": "stela-fes",
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "libs/stela-app/tsconfig.lib.json",
              "libs/stela-app/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**", "!libs/stela-app/**"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/stela-app/jest.config.js",
            "tsConfig": "libs/stela-app/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "passWithNoTests": true,
            "setupFile": "libs/stela-app/src/test-setup.ts"
          }
        }
      },
      "schematics": {
        "@nrwl/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@nrwl/angular"
  },
  "schematics": {
    "@nrwl/angular:application": {
      "unitTestRunner": "jest",
      "e2eTestRunner": "cypress"
    },
    "@nrwl/angular:library": {
      "unitTestRunner": "jest"
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "testbed"
}
```

Comment: with which command does this message appear ? ng build or ng serve ?

Comment: I used 'ng serve app_name'

Comment: can you post your angular.json

Comment: Thanks, I have post my angular.json

Comment: you shouldn't post it as answer, can you edit your question and put it there ?

Comment: ^^ OK. I did it.

Answer (score 0):

First do:

```
npm update
```

After that, update Angular dependencies

```
ng update
```

And finally to update any mismatched dependencies

```
ng update --all --force
```

Let me know if it did the trick